# Why is NULL getting different result that nil?

Tags: iphone, ios4, null

For AVAudioPlayer, when I `initWithContentsOfURL:error:` if I pass nil it doesn't work, but if I pass NULL it does.  And in the documentation, it specifically says to pass NULL.  Why is this?

Comment: `nil` should work.  If it doesn't, it may be because it's an `NSError **error` instead of a `NSError *error`.  But `nil` should still work.

Comment: I imagine you'd get a warning, but no error, for passing nil instead of NULL.  They're both 0, after all.

Comment: No guarantee that they'll always be 0 though, just that `nil = (id)NULL;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why is because **nil** is usually used for an Objective-C object type, while **NULL** is used for c-style pointers

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect something else is going on. If you check the definition of nil, it's the same as NULL:

```
#ifndef nil
#define nil NULL
#endif /* ! nil */
```